# Summerize Array with Arrays in Objetcs with different Labels

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter, reduce

I have an Array with Objects, there some of them has same "Subarrays" but with different labels. I need to summarize those based on equality.

Comparing two different arrays is easy so far, but I am not sure how to do it in the same array. 
This is my array.

```
let array = [{
  label: 'sting1',
  subArray: ['A', 'B']
}, {
  label: 'sting2',
  subArray: ['B']
}, {
  label: 'sting3',
  subArray: ['A', 'B']
}]
```

As you can see, the Objects labeled with `String1` and `String3` has the same array. So now I need to summarize those. The result I need is is this:

```
let result = [{
  label: ['sting1', 'string3'],
  subArray: ['A', 'B']
}, {
  label: ['sting2'],
  subArray: ['B']
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to give you an option without the map and reduce. When learning javascript I usually preferred to always go back to simple syntax to learn what was happening.

let me know if that helped!

```js
let array = [{label: 'sting1', subArray: ['A', 'B']}, {label: 'sting2',subArray: ['B']}, {label: 'sting3', subArray: ['A', 'B']}]

result = [];
checkdups = [];

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    data = {
        label: [array[i].label],
        subArray: array[i].subArray
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {

        if (String(array[j].subArray) == String(array[i].subArray) && i != j) {
            data.label.push(array[j].label);
        }
    }

    if (checkdups.indexOf(String(array[i].subArray))==-1) {
        checkdups.push(String(array[i].subArray));
        result.push(data);
    }

}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: yapp, your are absolutely right! To understand the background technically. Thank you for that work. I never would have the idea doing it with loops this way. Thank you very much for your help!

:D

Answer (score 2):

The question is likely a generic "group by", though it involves some problematics, which mostly are:

- You need to group by an array of items. Because you didn't specify whether the threated array is the same by reference or by value, we need to assume that you probably need to compare every value singularly.
- About what said above, I'm assuming that your array consists of **primitives only**.
- The labels seems to be somewhat ordered by occurrence, so I'm assuming you want them to be collected in the **same order they appear in the original array**.

That said, you can use `Array.reduce` to traverse the original array and, progressively:

- Check whether the accumulator already has the desired key (unluckily, in your scenario, it can't be accomplished with a simple lookup. You could, technically, use a WeakMap, but that would be slightly more complex). In your case, the key is your subArray. So, if there is any item in the accumulator that has the subArray that is currently looped, you simply push the label to the existing one.
- If there is none, you simply push the currently looped item, **assuming you don't care about references**. If you don't want the original `array` values to be altered, **deep copy them first**.
- Once everything is done, simply return the accumulator and continue until it's finished.

Below is an example code **built to work with the scenario you posted**:

```js
let array = [{
  label: 'sting1',
  subArray: ['A', 'B']
}, {
  label: 'sting2',
  subArray: ['B']
}, {
  label: 'sting3',
  subArray: ['A', 'B']
}];

const grouped = array.reduce((acc, next) => {
  const { subArray } = next; // <-- acquire the subArray of the currently looped item.
  const exists = acc.find(({subArray: registeredSubArray}) => registeredSubArray.every(i => subArray.indexOf(i) > -1));
  // ^-- checks whether, in the accumulator, said subarray exists and if every item of the subarray is matched through indexOf against the accumulator looped item.
  if (exists) exists.label.push(next.label); // <-- if the item already exists, simply collect the label.
  else acc.push(Object.assign(next, {label: [next.label]})); // <-- otherwise, create a new object and assign the label as an array of labels instead of a single label.
  return acc; // finally, return the accumulator and continue.
}, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: Wow, I dont know what to say. Thank you for this massive answer! I also would like to mark your answer as Solution. You did a lot of work to describe the background of how to use `reduce` and its behavior. But Stackoverflow only allows one answer makred as solution. But I know I will need to use your Answer a lot in the future and I can learn a lot from you. 

Thank you for your hard work! It really clears out for me, what reduce does, which I never had understood in the past. You described this better then Mozillas docs - abstract but pragmatic. 

Thank you very much!! :D

Comment: @equaliser Thanks, I'm glad this helped. As a side note, Nenad's answer above is slightly cleverer than mine, in my opinion, since he thought about doing the lookup through a unique generated key, which is way more efficient than my approach (which has an O(n) complexity inside the reduce, while his solution is less complex over time, should be O(log n) if I'm not wrong). Overall, so, Nenad's solution is the current best one out there in my opinion, just wanted to point that out, though I'm glad you've enjoyed my considerations ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your subArray contains only primitive types so no objects, arrays or functions you can create key with `sort` and `join` methods, then you use `reduce` to build the result.

```js
let array = [{"label":"sting1","subArray":["A","B"]},{"label":"sting2","subArray":["B"]},{"label":"sting3","subArray":["A","B"]}]

const map = array.reduce((r, e) => {
  const key = e.subArray.sort().join('-');
  if (!r.has(key)) r.set(key, { ...e, label: [e.label]});
  else r.get(key).label.push(e.label);
  return r;
}, new Map)

const result = [...map.values()];
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to go through each object in the array and group it by matching subArray.

We can find the matching subArray by using `Array.prototype.findIndex` if it is found we add to to the existing label array else create a new label array and push the object in the final array:

```js
const array = [{"label":"sting1","subArray":["A","B"]},{"label":"sting2","subArray":["B"]},{"label":"sting3","subArray":["A","B"]}];

const res = array.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const idx = acc.findIndex(o => (o.subArray.length === obj.subArray.length) 
                      && o.subArray.every(e => obj.subArray.includes(e)));
  if(idx >= 0){
     acc[idx].label.push(obj.label);
  }else{
     obj.label = [obj.label];
     acc.push(obj);
  }
  return acc;
    
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I was thinking about, that the `reduce` prototype would help me out, but to be honest, since now I had no deeper look into into reduce, so I never would have the idea using this that way. Your solution is very simple and understandable. 

I wish I could mark your Answer as solution too, but stackoverflow does not allow me to. But I will need to use your method a lot. You opened my eyes using `Reduce`

Thank you very very much! :D

Comment: @equaliser Thank you for your kind words! I wish you would select my answer too, but select the one which helped you the most.